# Is it possible to customize Salesforce1 header?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, aura

Is there a way to add a button or edit an existing button ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible at this time. Only thing you can do is customize the [colors](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_sf1_branding_edit.htm&language=en_US&type=0).